# How to use item touch helper with heterogeneous view types?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I am following this tutorial [Item touch helper example](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/) (well actually just the item touch helper part and that too because I want the red background with the delete icon seen when swiping). But I have two different view types in my recyclerview. How would I go about implementing it? I am stuck on this line

```
final View foregroundView = ((CartListAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
```

in the **RecyclerItemTouchHelper.java** on the **onChildDraw** method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `ViewHolder` instances have a method `getItemViewType()` which will return the same value your adapter originally returned from its own `getItemViewType()` method when the ViewHolder was created. You can use the value here to choose which of your own ViewHolder subclasses to cast to:

```
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
    int viewType = viewHolder.getItemViewType();

    if (viewType == MY_FIRST_TYPE) {
        ((MyFirstSubclass) viewHolder).foo();
        // ...
    } else if (viewType == MY_SECOND_TYPE) {
        ((MySecondSubclass) viewHolder).bar();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```